# GeoTools getFeatures takes forever

Tags: features, geotools, oracle-dbms

I wrote the following method as an onClick handler. First and second click, I got result from DB. By the third time, the code stopped in the "getFeatures(trgtFilter)" line and didn't return. In debug mode, I saw that it is waiting for DB connection. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I'm using GeoTools 15 and Oracle 12.

```
private Geometry getNewGeometry(String refID) throws Exception {
    if (trgLayer != null) {
        Connection con = null;
        OracleConnection oraCon=null;
        FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> itr = null;
        try {
            con = ((JDBCDataStore) srcLayer.getFeatureSource().getDataStore()).getConnection(Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT);              
            oraCon = (OracleConnection) new DelegatingConnection(con).getInnermostDelegate();

            Filter trgtFilter = editTask.getConfiguration().getReferenceFilter(trgLayer, refID);
            FeatureCollection fc = trgLayer.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(trgtFilter);
            itr = fc.features();
            if (!itr.hasNext())
                return null;
            ...
            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{? = call MY_FUNC(?,?)}");
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "SDO_GEOMETRY");
            cs.setObject(2, trgStrct);
            cs.setObject(3, srcStrct);
            cs.execute();
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (itr != null)
                itr.close();
            if (oraCon != null) {
                try {
                    oraCon.close();
                    if (con != null && !con.isClosed())
                        con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have lots of layers in your Oracle? Getting Oracle connection is very slow, but if you have a connection pool with established connection you can connection from the pool much faster.

Comment: I have 10 layers. I think I've reached the maximum connections. Seems like the previous connection is not properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about [connection pooling](http://www.coderanch.com/t/642629/Tomcat/DB-Connection-leakage-tomcat-dbcp) and found that I only need to close the "parent" connection.

```
finally {
    if (itr != null)
        itr.close();
    if (con != null && !con.isClosed())
        con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be opening your own connections, let GeoTools manage that for you. I have used the following code (with a PostGIS connection as I don't have Oracle installed) and it is fine. The main trick is to make sure you [close your featurereaders/featurecollections/iterators](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html), otherwise they will hang on to a connection until they are garbage collected. I've just checked and I can lock the following up by commenting out the `reader.close()` line.

```
 HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
   /* params.put("url", countryURL);*/
    params.put( "dbtype", "postgis");
    params.put( "host", "127.0.0.1");
    params.put( "port", 5432);
    params.put( "schema", "c10m");
    params.put( "database", "naturalearth");
    params.put( "user", "ian");
    params.put( "passwd", "*****");

    ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    if (ds == null) {
      throw new IOException("couldn't open " + params);
    }
    Name name = ds.getNames().get(0);
    name = new NameImpl("admin_0_countries");
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
      double x = Math.random()*360.0-180.0;
      double y = Math.random()*180.0-90.0;
      /*Filter f = CQL.toFilter("contains(the_geom,point("+x+" "+y+"))");*/
      Filter f = CQL.toFilter("contains(geom,point("+x+" "+y+"))");

      Query query = new Query(name.getLocalPart(), f);
      FeatureReader<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> reader;
      if((reader=ds.getFeatureReader(query, Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT))!=null) {
        try {
        if(reader.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(reader.next().getAttribute("admin"));
        }else {
          System.out.println("miss");
        }
        }finally {
          reader.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with opening my own connections? The Oracle connection is used to make a db request. PS: I updated the code.